# Issue with object property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

My code yields the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

First, here's the screenshot of the table
[image: Table row]

**Note:**
This table are the assigned work schedule of the student.

Let's proceed to my code:

```
function saveWorkSched(){
    // listWorkSched
    var arr=[];
    var getSAWorkSched=[[],[]];
    var wsCounter=0;
    var wsCounter2=0;
    var j = 0;

    $("#listWorkSched td").each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).text());
    });
      console.log(arr);
    for(j;j<arr.length;j++){
      if(wsCounter2<=2){
        getSAWorkSched[wsCounter][wsCounter2]=arr[j];
        wsCounter2++;
      }else{
        wsCounter++;
        wsCounter2=0;
        getSAWorkSched[wsCounter][wsCounter2]=arr[j];
        wsCounter2++;
      }
    }
  }
```

**1st phase:**
after the user create the work schedule this will be stored in `arr` variable.

**2nd phase:**
the `arr` value will converted to multi-dimensional array and will be stored in `getSAWorkSched` variable

after the 3rd loop an error will occurred. it means that every time I create a work schedule more than 2 the error will trigger.

```
else{
        wsCounter++;
        wsCounter2=0;
        getSAWorkSched[wsCounter][wsCounter2]=arr[j]; // Here's the code where the error specified based on the console of my browser
        wsCounter2++;
      }
```

Comment: Define "won't work". What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: after third loop this error pop-up on my console on the browser: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` and here's the code where the browser specified: `getSAWorkSched[wsCounter][wsCounter2]=arr[j];` on the `else` part.. just want you to know that when the tables has only 2 rows it will work... but when there are 3 rows and above that error will pop-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the nested array that you try to access. It really comes down to the same principle: you address the following:

```
    getSAWorkSched[wsCounter][wsCounter2]
```

... with a `wsCounter` value that is eventually getting to 2, but you have only defined two nested arrays in the initialisation of `getSAWorkSched`, so `getSAWorkSched[2]` does not exist -- it will give you `undefined`. Trying to get an array element from nothing (`undefined`) is not possible. So add this line before it in the `else` bock:

```
    getSAWorkSched[wsCounter] = []; // <--- Add this
    getSAWorkSched[wsCounter][wsCounter2]=arr[j];
```

#### More elegant code

You could use `$.map` and `slice` to write this in a more elegant way:

```
function saveWorkSched() {
    var arr = $.map($("#listWorkSched td"), function (td) {
        return $(td).text();
    });
    var getSAWorkSched = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j += 3) {
        getSAWorkSched.push(arr.slice(j, j + 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: where will I put that code? before `for`? or inside `for`?

Comment: oh wait I think I got it... I'll update you in a few seconds

Comment: it worked now! thanks! I'll accept your answer.. I didn't know that's the reason why the error triggered.. that code is from my php I just convert it to javascript... but why is it that in javascript need to initialize again but different in PHP

Comment: Added more elegant alternative. And yes, PHP will create nested arrays for you silently when you refer to an index. Not so with JavaScript. Different language = different rules ;-)

Comment: thanks for enlighten me... I didn't know that some rules in array are different with php & javascript

Comment: by the way, I want to accept your additional code but as I can understand the code it create a single array... on my system that I working on is not suitable to your code... BUT I will keep it for future reference.. thanks a lot!